# JavaScript object properties copy syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading some JavaScript code and saw a line of code similar to this.

```
const {name, password, email} = user;
```

I tried searching around but could not figure out what this syntax is called so I am not able find the documentation. Is this a new JavaScript syntax? What is it called? What does it do exactly?

Comment: Object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment